# Can Visual Studio's Web Performance Test be used as a stress test for a web farm?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, performance-testing

Visual Studio Ultimate has a "Web performance Test" feature that allows you to specify the number of times a test is run.  But it looks like it runs those tests one after another.  eg if you specify 100 it ill run the test 100 times in a row.

[image]

Is it possible to run the 100 tests at the same time in order to stress test the web app?  And if not, what does Visual Studio provide that can be use for stress testing?

Comment: Have you tried doing a stress test? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293540.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using VS Ultimate, you can perform a number of tests on a web application.
From [here:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293540.aspxcapacities.)

> When you add Web performance tests to a load test, you simulate
> multiple users opening simultaneous connections to a server and making
> multiple HTTP requests. You can set properties on load tests that
> widely apply to the individual Web performance tests.
>
> **Smoke**: How your application performs under light loads for short durations.
>
> **Stress**: To determine if your application will run successfully for a sustained duration under heavy load.
>
> **Performance**: How responsive your application is.
>
> **Capacity Planning**: How your application performs at various capacities.

In this case, you will want to create a stress test using the **New Load Test Wizard**.

Hope it helps!